# How to get Solr Extraction Handler to extract multiple META tags with the same name?

Tags: solr, cell, handler, extract

I am uploading some HTML documents to the SOLR extraction handler (Solr-Cell), which have META elements in the head in this form:

```
<meta name="product" content="firstproduct" />
<meta name="product" content="anotherproduct" />
```

My schema has product defined as a multi-valued field:

```
<field name="product" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

I want *both* products to be added to the index within this field. Unfortunately, something is going wrong - only the last product is successfully recorded.

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, [it's an open issue](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1803).